# openpyxl formula blank in output excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to use the Excel AVERAGE formula to get the average of columns in a file. I am doing this like so:

```
font = Font(name="Calibri", bold=True)

ws.cell(100, 1).value = "Mean"  # row 100 is the average row
ws.cell(100, 1).font = font

col_range = [2, 3, 4]  # the columns to average
for col_index in col_range:
    cell = ws.cell(100, col_index)  
*   cell.value = f"=AVERAGE({cell.column_letter}2:{cell.column_letter}98)"
    cell.font = font
wb.save(out_file)
```

However, when I open the Excel file, the average cells are empty:

[image: excel_file]

As you can see, the cells in row 100 are empty apart from the "Mean" cell. There is no formula in the other cells whatsoever, but the markup of the cell **did** work (bold text).

When printing the formulas indicated with `*` in the above code, I see this:

```
=AVERAGE(B2:B98)
=AVERAGE(C2:C98)
=AVERAGE(D2:D98)
```

This is how I want it to be.

When I do something like `cell.value = "test"` instead of the formula, then this **does** work:

[image: working_excel_file]

I thought this might be a language issue since my Excel is in Dutch, and AVERAGE=GEMIDDELDE in my language, but even if I use GEMIDDELDE, then this will still result in empty cells.

Any ideas on why this isn't working? I should probably mention that the Excel file I am doing this in is created right before with a script, but I do properly save it and then open it again to enter the formulas.

**EDIT:**
I did just find this in the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html):

```
>>> from openpyxl import Workbook
>>> wb = Workbook()
>>> ws = wb.active
>>> # add a simple formula
>>> ws["A1"] = "=SUM(1, 1)"
>>> wb.save("formula.xlsx")
```

> NB you must use the English name for a function and function arguments must be separated by commas and not other punctuation such as semi-colons.

If I follow this step by step, then this works. However, this code uses `Workbook()`, but I use `load_workbook()`, and then it still doesn't work.

I tried using `,` instead of `;`, but this also didn't work. I think it's weird that you are not supposed to use `;`, because isn't the value of a cell just a string? I feel like `openpyxl` doesn't do anything to it, but yet you're not supposed to use `;`.

I also downloaded the English version of Excel to rule out the language. I also tested using `,` and `.` as the decimal separators in the cells that have to be averaged, but none of this works either. I feel like this is more an `openpyxl` issue now; I'm using version `3.0.5`. If you use `Workbook()`, formulas work, but `load_workbook()` just doesn't work. Any tips would still be appreciated though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... So, I have something that works now. When using `load_workbook()`, there is a `data_only` flag you can use (from [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)):

> There are several flags that can be used in load_workbook.
>
> - data_only controls whether cells with formulae have either the formula (default) or the value stored the last time Excel read the sheet.

I do more operations on the same Excel file than just creating the average row in the question, and when doing these operations, I open the workbook like so:

```
    wb = load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
```

Turns out that this makes the formulas not work anymore! When I removed this flag everywhere where I open the workbook, the AVERAGE formula works. Make sure that if you select a range of columns, then to still use `:`, but if you use a formula with multiple arguments, then separate them with `,` and **not** `;`.

Oh and btw, you can load the file in Excel in a different language; as long as you put the formula in English in your code, it will translate appropriately.